# Add object to json with robot framework

Tags: json, robotframework

```
${json_obj}=    Load JSON From File    C:\\temp\\example.json
JSONLibrary.Delete Object From Json    ${json_obj}    $..address
```

This is how to delete address.

But if I want to add address with some value, how to do it?

Tried this but it does not add:

```
${object_to_add}=    Create Dictionary    latitude=13.1234    longitude=130.1234

${json_obj}=    Add Object To Json     ${json_obj}    $..address    ${object_to_add}


{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "gender": "male",
    "favoriteColor": [
        "blue"
    ],
    "isMarried": false,
    
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "type": "iPhone",
        "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    }, {
        "type": "home",
        "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that after trying to delete "address", the json path "$..address" no longer exists and you won't be able to add objects to it.

You could check for the existence of the "address" key in the main object and if not exists then create it with the coordinates as the keys value

```
*** Settings ***
Library  JSONLibrary
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Add Objects

    ${current_record}    Load JSON From File   C:\\temp\\example.json   
    Delete Object From Json   ${current_record}   $..address 

    ${coords}      Create Dictionary    latitude=13.1234   longitude=130.1234

    # Check if the "address" key is in the object
    ${is_address_key}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Dictionary Should Contain Key  ${current_record}  address

    # If address key not exists then add coords to dictionary with key address and add to object directly
    IF  ${is_address_key}
        Add Object To Json   ${current_record}   $..address    ${coords}
    ELSE 
        ${address}  Create Dictionary  address=${coords}
        Add Object To Json   ${current_record}  $   ${address}
    END

    Dictionary Should Contain Key  ${current_record}[address]  latitude
    Log To Console  \n${current_record}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Got it working. Needed to create the new key